# Append to a queue without calling a destructor

Tags: c++, queue, linked-list

I have this class:

```
class user
{
private:
    string userid;
    string password;
public:
    user(){};
    user(string a, string b){userid = a; password = b;}
    ~user(){cout<<"Trace";};
    void    print ( ostream& out );
};
```

Every time I try to append to my queue this way `aqueue.append(user(userid, password);` it will append to my queue but it will call the destructor afterwards. The queue is a basic generic linked list pointing to the next cell. My question is: how to add to a class to a queue with out calling the destructor each time?

Comment: Assuming your queue works like `std::queue`, you can't. You copy the object into the queue, and the original is destroyed. It seems that's the same approach you've taken with your queue.

Comment: @BillyONeal can I get around this with pointers?

Comment: @Joe: Yes; but the extra memory allocations are going to cost far more than a few destructor calls. (Honestly, a linked list is a horrible data structure in most every case; you'd be better off using something like the way std::deque, or a circular buffer)

Comment: What's wrong with the destructor being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store pointers (e.g. raw pointers, `std::auto_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr`) to the objects you wish to store, rather than the objects themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It is looks like you are creating object in stack & passing it to queue for append.
And as queue is accepting object (not pointer or reference) it may deep copy object & as scope of original object get finish it will get removed(destructed).

create object using new operator on heap & then pass it using reference or pointer.

Comment: Queue is your own class or STL?